# Bijection of isomorphic graphs with every vertex having the same degree

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, then there exists a bijection $f : V (G) \to V (H)$ such that
every vertex $u ∈ V (G)$ has the same degree as $f(u)$?

Is this true or false and why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- every isomorphism is a bijection with that property.

By definition of bijection, $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ are neighbors in $H$ if and only if $u$ and $v$ are neighbors in $G$. This means that if the neighbors of $u$ are $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ then the neighbors of $f(u)$ are exactly $\{f(v_1),f(v_2),\ldots,f(v_n)\}$, and because $f$ is a *bijection*, those two sets have the same size.